# Azure: Send device twin reported values to cosmos database

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub

I have a device twin whose reported properties are being updated and I would like to send the reported properties to (a) a database for longterm storage and (b) a power bi report for live values. How would I route these two endpoints?

The reported properties resemble the properties in [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/master/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_device_twin_and_methods_sample).

```
        "reported": {
            "lastOilChangeDate": "2016",
            "maker": {
                "makerName": "Fabrikam",
                "style": "sedan",
                "year": 2014
            },
            "state": {
                "reported_maxSpeed": 100,
                "softwareVersion": 1,
                "vanityPlate": "1I1"
            },
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the Device Twin change event which gives details whenever there is change in the device twin. Check the following screenshot.

[image]

Your flow will be go like as following

**Azure IoT Hub** ------> **Event Hub Trigger Azure Function** ------> **Azure CosmosDB**

Following is the Explanation

**Azure IoT**

See the preceding image for message routing configuration using the device twin change event.

Steps

- Goto Azure IoT hub Resource
- Find Message Routing Option
- Click on Add Route
- Choose the route name
- Choose **Built in Events** from Endpoint dropdown list
- Choose **Device Twin Change Events** from Data Source
- Write the route query (if required) to filter your specific reported
  properties

**Even Hub Trigger Azure Function**

Create the Event hub trigger Azure function to listen the device twin change event.

- Create the Azure function with Event hub trigger Azure function
  template.
- Find the Built-in endpoints option from IoT Hub resource
- Copy the Event Hub compatible endpoint connection string. This will
  act as a event hub. so you don't need to create the separate event
  hub which will cost you extra.
- Configure the Function binding with the preceding steps details
- Now whenever there is change in the twin, then the function will
  be get trigger and you will get the reported properties because in
  routing query we filter to get only reported properties else you will
  get the other properties which are in the device twin.

**Cosmos DB**

Now we have the reported properties in the azure function, you can create the custom code in the preceding Azure function to insert the reported properties payload into the Azure Cosmos DB.

I hope it will give some hint to you. If required any help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks @vithal, I was able to set up the message routing and create an Azure function, which currently just logs the updated device twin and is viewable in the log stream. Since the twin is a json file, it just occurred to me I could instead use the twin's json file as a power bi data source. Is this a feasible option? If so, how would I grab this json from the function? Or if not, could you please provide further insight on the code required to insert the reported properties payload into the cosmos db? Thank you.

Comment: if I correctly understood your question. You mean to say instead of storing into the cosmos DB can I show data in power BI directly using Azure Function? Yes you can directly show the data in Power BI from Azure function that is whatever JSON you are getting in Azure function. First you need to create the Streaming Dataset in Power BI and from azure function just push data to the power BI streaming dataset URI.

Answer (score 0):

1. IoT Hub supports Azure blob storage natively, [here's a tutorial on how to hook that up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing).
2. For live data visualization, you need to setup an [azure stream analytics job](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/stream-analytics/), (this can get expensive if you aren't careful). Once data flows into ASA you can setup a realtime data source in PowerBI, [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-power-bi)

Comment: Thanks for the response and resources. If I understand correctly, both solutions you gave do not implement the device twin but rather involves sending device telemetry to the IoT Hub. Is there a way to route data from the device twin (ie. the reported properties) to some storage (like cosmos database or blob storage)?

Comment: Ah, apologies, I completely blanked on that. In the case of device twins, you'll need to use the iothub query language and use a function app to push that through to blob https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language

Comment: As for realtime power bi, you'll need to add a message enrichment and query on that using stream analytics, after that it's the same as the normal iothub to powerbi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-message-enrichments-overview

Comment: If your pricing tier allows, it may be better for you to use device-to-cloud messaging as that's better supported out of the box

Comment: What trigger type would you use for the function app? Ideally the blob storage data should update whenever a device twin's reported properties change. Also, why use blob storage over a cosmos db? I've found arguments supporting both, but not in the case of using device twins. Lastly, I've dabbled in the device-to-cloud messaging and I'm curious - what direct comparisons can be made between using that messaging versus updating device twin properties? Or can you point me towards any good resources there? Thanks so much for your help.